# No module named 'sklearn.neural_network._multilayer_perceptron'

Tags: python, joblib

I want to call a joblib file that contains MLPRegressor modele but the error appear

import joblib
mlpr = joblib.load("C:/Users/Haytham/OneDrive/Bureau/PFE - App/model.pkl")

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neural_network._multilayer_perceptron'

Answer (score 2):

Installing specific version on scikit-learn solved my problem.

```
pip install "scikit_learn==0.22.2.post1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your scikit-learn with:

```
conda update scikit-learn
```

Comment: I have saved radomforestclassifier model to a file using pickle but when I try to open the file: model = pickle.load(f)

I get this error: builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble._forest'

Comment: @CelluleBoukham I have the same problem, I think there are different python and module versions.... I need to fix it now, somehow